# Neovim does not restore terminal cursor on exit

Tags: vimrc, neovim, terminal, cursor

The cursor of my `gnome-terminal` is an `underline _`.

I am using Neovim and I want the cursor in Command Mode to be: `block |`

`set guicursor=n:block-Cursor`

When I exit from Neovim I want the cursor back to `underline`. **This is not happening.** The cursor is staying as a `block |`.

**Why isn't Neovim restoring the cursor back to the original one set for the terminal ?**

Is there a plugin available to do that ? How do I do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can and add this to your `init.vim`:

```
augroup RestoreCursorShapeOnExit
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimLeave * set guicursor=a:hor20
augroup END
```

See `:h guicursor` for details.

The reason it isn't done automatically is [there's no way to query the terminal cursor shape](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/4867#issuecomment-223725876)

Comment: Why are you using such a complicated syntax ? Why not just use `autocmd VimLeave * set guicursor=a:hor20` ? Why use `augroup` and what does `autocmd!` do ?

Comment: Is to avoid duplicating the auto commands every time you source `init.vim`. `autocmd!`clears them. See a detailed explanation [here](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html)

Comment: But my `init.vim` is only sourced once during startup. Right ? So what is the problem if I don't remove them ?

Comment: Then you should be OK, although it’s common to manually source the init file when changed instead of starting a new instance. I even have an auto command for that. In any case, this particular auto command is so small that I think it is safe for you to try it without clearing it for a while

Comment: This doesn't work when suspending vim to background.

Comment: @Itachi you can add as many events as you want. See `:help autocommand`. In this case `autocmd VimLeave,VimSuspend * set guicursor=a:hor20` should work